# How to delete a large number of post from WordPress database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In WordPress woocommerce site I have custom  post_type `klaviyo_shop_cart`  = =1137717 number of post  which I don't need them so I decided to delete them from my database. to do this I have tried few plugin but due to limitation I failed to delete them.

My PHP method which can only handle 3000 post deletion i cannot increase these number. if i increase it shows 500 error.

```
<?php
$number = 3000 ;
$mycustomposts = get_posts( 
        array( 
        'post_type' => 'klaviyo_shop_cart', 
        'numberposts' => $number
        )
    );

    foreach( $mycustomposts as $mypost ) {
     // Delete's each post.
    wp_delete_post( $mypost->ID, true);
    // Set to False if you want to send them to Trash.
    }
    echo '<h3 style=:"color:red;"> DELETED!</h3>' . $number ;

?>
```

its very slower it an delete 3000 post at a time. SO I want to try bellow sql query to delete post. I know that I cannot delete `1137717` number of post at time so I need a better solution. my question is there any way to delete `50000` in a single query ?

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='klaviyo_shop_cart';
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM wp_posts);
DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM wp_posts);
```

I found this from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66242/how-to-empty-wordpress-custom-post-database-table)

this huge number of post can delete a batch operation on 50000 post delete at once.

Comment: Nobody can say anything about the capabilities of your MySQL server. That's a weird question.

Comment: What "limitation"? If your server is slow this will take a long time to complete. If you can read-only lock the site you could try pulling down the database, cleaning it up locally on a faster computer, and uploading the cleaned up result.

Comment: my server is dedicated server and Database size is too big to complete locally

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you stating that you have 500 posts of the custom `post_type` and you want to delete those with the above SQL statements?  Or are you asking for help modifying the SQL statements you posted so you can delete just 500 posts of that type at a time?  As to performance, it entirely depends on your server, as others have noted in the other comments.

Comment: @JustinR.I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Select Data to check**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, post_title, post_type, post_status, d.taxonomy, e.name
FROM wp_filn_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_filn_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_filn_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_filn_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_filn_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id )
WHERE a.post_type = 'klaviyo_shop_cart'
```

**If You Satisfied then Delete**

```
DELETE a,b,c
FROM wp_filn_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_filn_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_filn_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_filn_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_filn_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id )
WHERE a.post_type = 'klaviyo_shop_cart'
```